# Quartz.net - Could not load file or assembly Common.Logging Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net, common.logging

Im using Quartz.net in my project, and suddenly I get this exception :

> Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Logging, Version=3.0.0.0...

I have no idea why it poped, everything was just fine, and the quartz worked,
And suddenly it didn't.
Why?

Comment: Ensure you have that dll along what quartz.net dll

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when you ad a reference to a new assembly that also uses Common.Logging, but a different version. When the project build it picks up the incorrect version and then starts to complain as Quartz.net is bound to a particular version.

One fix for this is to do a `bindindRedirect` in the app.config.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a few hours, in which I opened another project with exactly the same code which worked, I figured out that for some reason, the quartz is creating the Common.Logging dll after rebuilding the project, and that for some reason it didn't create it in my original project, so I just copied the dlls.